# 3DES/DES encryption using the JCE - generating an acceptable key

Tags: java, .net, jce

I'm working on a project that ***requires*** 3DES encryption in Java. The issue is that I've been (and will continue to be) supplied with a 128-bit hex key like "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF". Conversion to bytes is no issue. What ***is*** the issue, however, is that the Java Cryptographic Extensions API will choke on this key, saying it is invalid. I gather that the MSB of each byte is merely a parity bit, so the JCE expects me to remove those (or so I think). In .NET, however, I can specify the key as supplied, and it quietly handles the encryption/decryption with no complaints.

Is there any way I can generate the kind of key the JCE expects from the kind of key I'm supplied?

I've found that the JCE allows you specify an 8-byte key for DES encryption, so I tried implementing 3DES as DES EDE using half of the supplied key. However, I'm still getting inconsistent results with .NET.

Here's the Java code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte [] plain = "I eat fish every day".getBytes("utf-8");

        byte [] keyBytes = new byte [] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00
            };

        byte [] key2Bytes = new byte [] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0  }; // actual keys replaced with dummies.

        SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");
        SecretKey keySpec2 = new SecretKeySpec(key2Bytes, "DES");

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);

        Cipher e_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");

        e_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec2, iv);

        byte [] cipherText = e_cipher.doFinal(plain);
        cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        cipherText = e_cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

        System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText));
    }
}
```

and here's the .NET code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace EncryptionDemo
{
    class Program
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // TODO: Implement Functionality Here
        var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I eat fish every day");
        var keyBytes = new byte [] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
         0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
         0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
         0x00,  0x00, 0x00, 0x00  };

        var tripleDES = TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        var transform = tripleDES.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, new byte [8]);

        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        var cStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        cStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
        cStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        //memStream.Position = 0;
        var cipherBytes = memStream.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Ciphertext: " + Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes));

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Both produce different outputs (some characters in the Base64 string are the same)

Comment: "Choke" is really vague. How about an actual error message?

Comment: @erickson: sorry about that. please look below

Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 16 bytes at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineGetKeySize(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
 at Main.main(Main.java:30)

Comment: For context clarification purposes, the question comes from the jpos mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jpos-users/sfXGf2gwQhY/xN63ze305bwJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Sun provider doesn't accept 16-byte 3DES keys, but the BouncyCastle provider does. I just tried it out and it works like a charm - it produces the same output as the .NET code!

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        byte [] plain = "I eat fish every day".getBytes("utf-8");

        byte [] keyBytes = new byte [] { (byte) 0xC1, (byte) 0x57, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x08,
            (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xD3,
            (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x43,
            (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0xE6, (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0x75 };


        SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);

        Cipher e_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");

        e_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);

        byte [] cipherText = e_cipher.doFinal(plain);

        System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

3DES keys are 192 bits long.

How are you creating the `SecretKey` instance? What error message to you get?

---

The Java code in your *question* is using DES, not "Triple DES". The algorithm name should be `"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. The code in your *answer* probably works because you got the algorithm right, not because you switched providers. The SunJCE provider in Java 6 will accept 128-bit keys (and use keying option 2). I am not sure about older versions.

Comment: 3DES keyring option 2 uses 128 bits (or 112 bits if you leave out the parity) - k1 and k3 are the same.  Maybe that's what his project is using?  The JCE appears to support 112 bit 3DES keys.  It also seems from the docs that JCE wants the parity bits removed (ie., 112 or 168 bits, not 128 or 192).

Comment: It depends on the provider. The SunJCE will accept a 128-bit key (112-bit actual keying material), from which it infers that you want keying option 2. Other providers may only support (the more secure) keying option 1, which requires 192 bits. The parity bits must be *included* in the key.

Comment: I had the same issue with some new code:
    String plainText = "I eat fish every day";
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte [] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("utf-8"));
    System.out.println("Key: " + hexKey);
    System.out.println("Encrypted data: " + Hex.encodeHexString(cipherBytes));
---- EXCEPTION DETAILS -----
    Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 16 bytes at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineGetKeySize(DashoA13*..)

Answer (score 1):

In the [jPOS](http://jpos.org) project, the problem is worked around by always using either single-length (8-byte) or triple-length (24-byte) keys. Let's say your clear double-length key (in bytes) is AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB. All code in the jPOS project I've seen so far that uses the JCE appends the first 8 bytes again to the clear key, so it becomes a triple-length key as such: AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB AAAAAAAA. It seems the Sun provider does accept this material for creating a SecreKeySpec, as it is 192 bits long, as @erickson mentioned.